# Fitting bivariate normal distribution with covariate-dependent correlation parameters

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, fitting, bivariate

Suppose we fit
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
        X \\ Y
    \end{bmatrix} \sim
    \mathcal{N} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\ 0
    \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1         & \rho(C) \\
        \rho(C) & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \right),
$$
where $\rho(C)$ is a function of covariate $C$ in the parametric form of $\rho(C) = g(\alpha + \beta C)$ ($g$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $[-1,1]$). And we are interested in estimating $\widehat{\alpha}, \widehat{\beta}$. I assume this should be a well-studied question, so I wonder if the MLE can be solved in an efficient way, other than the brute-force of calculating the likelihood and using general optimizer. I attach the naive code I use for now:

```py
def negloglik(params):
    a = params[0]
    b = params[1]
    print(a, b)
    nll = 0
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        # for now g is a clip function, but can be replaced with logistic.
        rho = np.clip(a + b * covar[i], -1, 1)
        nll -= multivariate_normal.logpdf(
            data[i, :],
            mean=[0, 0],
            cov=np.array([[1, rho], [rho, 1]]),
            allow_singular=True,
        )
    return nll

# use overall correlation as start
avg_coef = np.corrcoef(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])[0, 1]
model = minimize(
    negloglik, np.array([avg_coef, 0]), method="L-BFGS-B"
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't code $\rho$ as a linear function since it is restricted to the range $(-1,1)$ in order for the covariance matrix to be invertible.

Comment: thanks @user277126 i update my description to include this link function